# in exact target can we retrieve contacts in business unit, the contacts being from Europe only?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automationstudio

I need to retrieve contacts who are from Europe

I have looked into all standard reports 
and contact reports

is there automation to run which gives only contact email ids with the email ending in `.eu`?

Comment: Is this in Marketing Cloud or Sales/Service Cloud?

Answer (score 3):

You can’t assume that your contacts from Europe will have .eu as top level domain (TLD) on their email domains, and the use of this TLD is not very widespread.

I will assume that within your data model, there is a field defining country/locale for each contact. You would then need to run a Query activity to do a count of your contacts, grouped by locale. This will allow you to select the numbers belonging to European locales.

Comment: Just one thing I would not do: Abbreviations tend to be missunderstood, i would rather write top level domain (TLD) than only TLD. Some people might not get it.

Comment: Voila - added little more explanation :-)